# In Solidworks Hole Toolbox, what is Thread Minor Diameter according to DIN 13-1

Tags: measurements, solidworks, cad

Dear StackExchange Community,

I recently discovered how to use the Toolbox customization to specify new threads in Solidworks 2021 SP2.0, such as ISO fine metric threads (DIN 13-3- ... -9). However, when I started populating the Thread Data of my thread (M10x0.75), I was faced with the problem of matching the columns of the Thread Data with the ISO norm values. I could get that the **Thread Minor Diameter Inside** is equivalent to *D1* in DIN 13-1 based on the values entered for already defined threads, such as M2x0.4.

[image: Image of DIN 13-1 definition I found from a Google search. It looks like the one I have on paper.]

However, I don't understand what the **Thread Minor Diameter** is. Initially, I thought it would be *d3* in DIN 13-1, but for M2x0.4, *d3* = 1.509, and Thread Minor Diameter for M2x0.4 in Solidworks is marked as 1.548.

[image: Screenshot of the default thread definitions in the Solidworks Toolbox]

Nobody in his right mind would check those values, that anyway do not appear in the drawings, but as an OCD person, this has been bugging me for too long, and I would appreciate if someone can explain this **Thread Minor Diameter** value in light of the DIN 13-1 norm to me.

Thank you for your help, and take care,

David

Comment: Here is a reference you could compare against: [Screw Threads on RoyMech](https://roymech.org/Useful_Tables/Screws/Thread_tol.html) ... d3 looks like the male thread root diameter

Comment: Thanks Pete, I'll have a carefull look at your resource, and update this post accordingly :)

Answer (score 0):

I determined what Thread Minor Diameter is. I found that it is related to "Thread Minor Diameter Inside" "minus" the *g es* offset shown in BS 3643-1:1981. The g tolerance offset value is directly related to the pitch (mm). I ploted the *g es* offset vs pitch to determine a linear fit regression equation and that's how I built my calculator below.

To summarize:

**Thread Minor Diameter** = **Thread Minor Diameter Inside** - *g es*

Where,
*g es* = bolt thread g tolerance upper deviation offset in **BS 3643-1:1981**

**Thread Minor Diameter Inside** = the D1 value you pointed out in DIN 13-1

I hope you find my calculator that takes all this into consideration useful:
https://www.cadifyservices.com/solidworks-custom-hole-wizard-thread-calculator

Here is an example of an M2x0.4 placed in my calculator: [image]

Here is the *g es* offset graph found in **BS 3643-1:1981**

[image]